# iconv only works once

Tags: c++, iconv

I try to make method which converts s-jis string to utf-8 string using `iconv`.
I wrote a code below,

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
size_t z = (size_t) BUF_SIZE-1;

bool sjis2utf8( char* text_sjis, char* text_utf8 )
{
  iconv_t ic;
  ic = iconv_open("UTF8", "SJIS"); // sjis->utf8
  iconv(ic , &text_sjis, &z, &text_utf8, &z);
  iconv_close(ic);
  return true;
}
int main(void)
{
  char hello[BUF_SIZE] = "hello";
  char bye[BUF_SIZE] = "bye";
  char tmp[BUF_SIZE] = "something else";

  sjis2utf8(hello, tmp);
  cout << tmp << endl;

  sjis2utf8(bye, tmp);
  cout << tmp << endl;
}
```

and, output should be

```
hello
bye
```

but in fact,

```
hello
hello
```

Does anyone know why this phenomenon occurs? What's wrong with my program?

*Note that "hello" and "bye" are Japanese s-jis strings in my original program, but I altered it to make program easy to see.*

Comment: please note that in your example z is decremented twice for every converted character.

Comment: also you should not cout utf8, you should cout ascii and wcout UCS2 on windows and UCS4 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misusing the `iconv` function by passing it the global variable `z`. The first time you call `sjis2utf8`, `z` is decremented to 0. The second call to `sjis2utf8` have no effect (z==0) and leaves `tmp` unchanged.

From the `iconv` [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.3.html) :

```
size_t iconv (iconv_t cd,
              const char* * inbuf, size_t * inbytesleft,
              char* * outbuf, size_t * outbytesleft);
```

> The iconv function converts one multibyte character at a time, and for each character conversion it increments *inbuf and decrements *inbytesleft by the number of converted input bytes, it increments *outbuf and decrements *outbytesleft by the number of converted output bytes, and it updates the conversion state contained in cd.

You should use two separate variables for the buffers lengths :

```
size_t il = BUF_SIZE - 1 ;
size_t ol = BUF_SIZE - 1 ;

iconv(ic, &text_sjis, &il, &text_utf8, &ol) ;
```

Then check the return value of `iconv` and the buffers lengths for the conversion success.

Comment: after first conversion z will overflow. In c/c++ it will wrap around if size_t is unsigned. If size_t is signed it will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: also in your second statement... to use 2 variables iconv will convert BUF_SIZE -1 characters and not only the string contents... in his example this is obvious because the null terminator will be converted also to 0 and cout will stop at that moment.

Comment: It depends on the `iconv` internal checks implementation. As you said in a previous comment : *z is decremented twice for every converted character*, but we don't know how it checks and stops when reaching 0. It can overflow (yes, size_t is unsigned).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const size_t BUF_SIZE=1024;


class IConv {
    iconv_t ic_;
public:
    IConv(const char* to, const char* from) 
        : ic_(iconv_open(to,from))    { }
    ~IConv() { iconv_close(ic_); }

     bool convert(char* input, char* output, size_t& out_size) {
        size_t inbufsize = strlen(input)+1;// s-jis string should be null terminated, 
                                           // if s-jis is not null terminated or it has
                                           // multiple byte chars with null in them this
                                           // will not work, or to provide in other way
                                           // input buffer length....
        return iconv(ic_, &input, &inbufsize, &output, &out_size);
     }
};

int main(void)
{
    char hello[BUF_SIZE] = "hello";
    char bye[BUF_SIZE] = "bye";
    char tmp[BUF_SIZE] = "something else";
    IConv ic("UTF8","SJIS");

    size_t outsize = BUF_SIZE;//you will need it
    ic.convert(hello, tmp, outsize);
    cout << tmp << endl;

    outsize = BUF_SIZE;
    ic.convert(bye, tmp, outsize);
    cout << tmp << endl;
}
```

- based on Kleist's answer

Answer (score 0):

You must put length of entry string in third parameter of `iconv`.

Try:

```
//...
int len = strlen(text_sjis);
iconv(ic , &text_sjis, &len, &text_utf8, &z);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t iconv (iconv_t cd,
          const char* * inbuf, size_t * inbytesleft,
          char* * outbuf, size_t * outbytesleft);
```

`iconv` changes the value pointed to by `inbytesleft`. So after your first run `z` is 0. To fix this you should use calculate the length of `inbuf` and store it in a local variable before each conversion.

It is described here: http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.3.html

And since you tagged this as C++ I would suggest wrapping everything up in a nice little class, as far as I can tell from the documentation you can reuse the `inconv_t` gained from `iconv_open` for as many conversions as you'd like.

```
#include <iconv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

const size_t BUF_SIZE = 1024;
size_t z = (size_t) BUF_SIZE-1;

class IConv {
    iconv_t ic_;
public:
    IConv(const char* to, const char* from) 
        : ic_(iconv_open(to,from))    { }

    ~IConv() { iconv_close(ic_); }

    bool convert(char* input, char* output, size_t outbufsize) {
        size_t inbufsize = strlen(input);
        return iconv(ic_, &input, &inbufsize, &output, &outbufsize);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    char hello[BUF_SIZE] = "hello";
    char bye[BUF_SIZE] = "bye";
    char tmp[BUF_SIZE] = "something else";
    IConv ic("UTF8","SJIS");


    ic.convert(hello, tmp, BUF_SIZE);
    cout << tmp << endl;

    ic.convert(bye, tmp, BUF_SIZE);
    cout << tmp << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is flawed because it will always convert 1024 characters/byte sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code works well only after I changed `const size_t BUF_SIZE` to `#define BUF_SIZE`, and it's nice because actually I have to convert from sjis string to utf8 string in other places.

Comment: @neagoegab: Changed to use strlen and passing outbufsize as argument. I see no need to make a local variable and pass a pointer to it as you've done in your copy.

Comment: BUF_SIZE is a constant... it can not be modified. iconv does write to outbufsize. Also him will need the size of the converted text for further manipulation.

Comment: @neagoegab My code doesn't modify BUF_SIZE, since it is passed by value. Who says he needs the length of the converted text? Many APIs simply expect null-terminated C-strings.

Comment: Oops, you are right about BUF_SIZE. My mistake. +one beer from me. About the c string, there are encodings where 0(zero) is a bad byte and null character is encoded as some other value. Libicu, iconv are working on byte sequences.